# How to add single parenthesis to string using angular or other java script function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plsql

I am utilizing Angular JS to manage write a batch of SQL test scripts.

I have a JSON file with multiple test scenarios, each scenario contains a list of projects to test:

```
 $scope.tests = [
 {
   "Date": "12/31/2017",
   "Project": "'93555','94558'",
   "STAT": "BDEC",
   "Type": "All",
   "Amount": 4000,
   "Purpose": "This purpose"
 },
 {
   "Date": "12/31/2017",
   "Project": "'93555','94558'",
   "STAT": "BDEC",
   "Type": "Elimination",
   "Amount": 6000,
   "Purpose": "That purpose"
 }
];
```

Then I used the projects which gets inserted into the angular

```
 <div ng-if="test.Project.length > 0">
    AND PROJECT in ({{test.Project}})
  </div>
```

Which Renders like this:

```
AND PROJECT in ('93555','94558')
```

PERFECT!
Then I need to log results

```
<div>DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'FAIL: {{test.STAT}} PROJECT {{ test.Project }}: EXPECTED {{test.Amount}} CALCULATED ' || RESULT || '***********'); </div>
```

Which Renders:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'FAIL: BDEC PROJECT '93555','94558': EXPECTED 4000 CALCULATED ' || RESULT || '***********');
```

In order to escape the single parenthesis inside the PUT_LINE, I need to add one more single parenthesis.  It should look like this.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'FAIL: BDEC PROJECT ''93555'',''94558'': EXPECTED 4000 CALCULATED ' || RESULT || '***********');
```

If I were only dealing with one object, I think I would write a function, but there are multiple objects.  The answer is probably obvious, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the Oracle's [quote operator   q'[]'](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218), then you don't need to escape the single quotation marks:

```
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( q'[FAIL: BDEC PROJECT '93555','94558': EXPECTED 4000 CALCULATED ]' || RESULT || '***********');
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Schurik